# Oracle can not create missing public synonym UTL_MAIL

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am running into a problem with synonym for Oracle.

One of the database package is giving me this error: **looping chain of synonym error**, on the line where UTL_MAIL.SEND is called. After reading several stack posts, I came up with the following query:

```
SELECT S.OWNER as SYN_OWNER, S.SYNONYM_NAME as SYN_NAME,
    S.TABLE_OWNER as OBJ_OWNER, S.TABLE_NAME as OBJ_NAME,
    O.STATUS as OBJ_STATUS
FROM DBA_SYNONYMS S
    LEFT JOIN DBA_OBJECTS O ON S.TABLE_OWNER = O.OWNER AND S.TABLE_NAME = O.OBJECT_NAME
WHERE (O.OWNER is null
    OR O.STATUS != 'VALID') and S.SYNONYM_NAME like '%UTL%'
```

I found that the UTL_MAIL synonym has a status of **null**, which indicates a missing synonym. ***However, there are many other public/private synonyms that are either invalid or missing(500+ of them)***. It seems like something didn't get set up correctly.

When I ran a simpler version of the query: `SELECT OWNER, SYNONYM_NAME,  TABLE_OWNER, TABLE_NAME FROM DBA_SYNONYMS`

I have the following result for UTL_MAIL:

```
Owner     SYNONYM_NAME TABLE_OWNER   TABLE_NAME
Public    UTL_MAIL     SYS           UTL_MAIL
```

**What I have tried so far :**

I logon as **SYSTEM** user and ran  `CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE PUBLIC SYNONYM "UTL_MAIL" FOR "SYS"."UTL_MAIL";`

The output says the synonym is created. However, when I ran the above query, its status still showing up as null.

What I need help with:

**How to create UTL_MAIL synonym properly?**

Comment: Maybe you should try rerunning \@catalog.sql and \@catproc.sql ?

Comment: Does the synonym exist more than once, and that is causing the loop? Who is shown as the owner in your query; or what does a simpler query like `SELECT OWNER, SYNONYM_NAME,  TABLE_OWNER, TABLE_NAME FROM DBA_SYNONYMS` show? (Might be useful to add the output of that to your question.)

Comment: @AlexPoole The owner showed up as "SYS", please see my edit

Comment: @PaulW I found these files under 'C:\app\MyUserName\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\RDBMS\ADMIN' Is there anything I need to look out for before running this?

Comment: Well, if this is just your personal Oracle database on your laptop, then I guess that makes you the DBA...  we normally put the database in restricted mode (shut it down, then start it up in restricted mode) and then run those scripts  using @ from sqlplus as sysdba. catalog.sql first, then catproc.sql. It will take a long time.. maybe a half hour. If however this is a Windows server and it's production, then obviously a trained DBA should take care of this in a scheduled outage window, and probably not before getting the OK from Oracle Support.

Comment: @PaulW Thanks for the information. It is for my local only. I was mainly worry about that if something goes wrong, it may interfere with my regular work(because it is a pain in the ass to fill out enough data so it works properly with the application even it is locally). I was wondering if there is something I should avoid.  If there isn't any major side effect, I guess I will give it a try since there are hundreds of missing/invalid synonyms. Seems like something is fundamentally wrong with the set up.

Comment: It should just recreate dictionary views, synonyms, and supplied PL/SQL packages to the installation image. Your data should remain untouched.

Comment: @PaulW tried this morning, ran both catalog.sql and cataproc.sql, the issue remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if you can find a looping synonym chain using a hierarchical query:

```
select owner, synonym_name, connect_by_iscycle CYCLE
from dba_synonyms
where connect_by_iscycle > 0
connect by nocycle prior table_name = synonym_name
and prior table_owner = owner
```

Comment: The result is empty

Comment: You might need to open a ticket with Oracle Support then on this.

Comment: I just realized that, after running both catalog.sql and cataproc.sql, the synonym is still missing. Is there any other script I should run as well?

Comment: At this point you really need to create an SR with Oracle Support